# App is running on galaxy tab 2 7.0 but not running on galaxy tab 7.0 plus

Tags: android

I have developed an app for kids and uploaded it on Google Play. It's working well on Galaxy Tab 10.1, Galaxy Tab 2 7.0, Galaxy Nexus, Galaxy Note and Galaxy S3. I've changed the api level from 2.2 to 4.1. A user downloaded the app on Galaxy Tab 7.0 Plus ICS and complained of an issue: the app hanged and was not responsive. At this time I do not have Galaxy Tab 7.0 Plus so cannot test it and figure out the error which hangs the app and makes it not responsive. Any help regarding this issue will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you get any details on the crash? A log from logcat would be nice

Comment: @miniBilli as i mentioned above that i did not have the Galaxy Tab 7.0 Plus at that time. But i checked it on Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 and its working well on it.

Comment: Use [ACRA](http://acra.ch) or the Play Store Developer Console to collect stack traces resulting from Application Not Responding (ANR) errors like this. That will give you some idea of where things may be going wrong.

Comment: @CommonsWare thankyou for the suggestion its new to me. will search on it for more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[tab2 vs tab plus](http://www.phonearena.com/news/Samsung-Galaxy-Tab-2-7.0-vs-Galaxy-Tab-7.0-Plus-spot-the-difference_id26920)

I think it will be the OS version related. Something with android version 3.0-3.2 vs 4.0

Comment: @matheszabi I tested on Galaxy Tab 10.1 which is 3.2 and the app is running well without any crashes. Galaxy Tab 7.0 is 3.2 but upgradeable to 4.0 ICS. and the customer have Galaxy tab 7.0 plus (ICS)

Comment: @Akhter that isn't the 7" device as the Tab Plus. Maybe something with drawable folders aren't good?

Comment: @matheszabi i uses drawable-mdpi for 7 inches devices