# Emulator for Galaxy Tab 7.0 Plus with ICS

Tags: android, android-emulator

How to make emulator for Galaxy Tab 7.0 Plus Ice Cream Sandwich. My App is running well on Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 but not runing on  Galaxy Tab 7.0 Plus with ICS .So i want to test my app on Galaxy Tab 7.0 Plus with ICS .At that time i have Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 but did not have Galaxy Tab 7.0 Plus ICS. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to make emulator for Galaxy Tab 7.0 Plus Ice Cream Sandwich

There really is no such concept. You are welcome to make an emulator image that emulates a 7" screen and runs Android 4.0. However, unless Samsung is publishing emulator AVDs -- and I am not aware that they are -- you cannot make an emulator that runs Samsung firmware.

Comment: thankyou for the correction . I asked this question beacuse of that question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056992/app-is-running-on-galaxy-tab-2-7-0-but-not-running-on-galaxy-tab-7-0-plus. Can you please give me any suggestion